# Micronaut, postgres issue

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, micronaut

following the below link
https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-data-access-jpa-hibernate/guide/index.html
i tried to connect postgresql,
when ran the test, all the test passed but when try to call the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/genres/1`

it is giving the following error:

```json
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error: Failed to inject value for parameter [entityManager] of class: example.micronaut.$GenreRepositoryImplDefinition$Intercepted\n\nMessage: No bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) 
      and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).\nPath Taken: 
     new $GenreControllerDefinition$Intercepted([GenreRepository genreRepository],BeanContext beanContext,Qualifier qualifier,Interceptor[] interceptors) --> 
      new $GenreRepositoryImplDefinition$Intercepted([EntityManager entityManager],ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,BeanContext beanContext,Qualifier qualifier,Interceptor[] interceptors)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you correctly specified list of packages to scan for entities. So, when you have your entity classes in the `my.project.entity` package, then you have to add this section into `application.yaml` configuration:

```yaml
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
        packages: 'my.project.entity'
```

---

And of course correct data source configuration in *application.yaml* file is required, where make sure, that you named the datasource as **default**:

```yaml
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/micronaut
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
```

---

Another reason can be missing dependency to JDBC configurations which preconfigures a simple JDBC connection for your project. So, make sure that you added it to `build.gradle` file. You can use `micronaut-jdbc-hikari` for example:

```
dependencies {
    runtime("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    ...
}
```

Or you can use `micronaut-jdbc-tomcat`, `micronaut-jdbc-dbcp` or `micronaut-jdbc-ucp`.

---

And also make sure, that you have all your repository interfaces annotated by `@Repository` annotation and entity classes by `@Entity` annotation. But without that it will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

created the project with https://micronaut.io/launch/ with selecting required features. it automatically given all the dependencies.

giving the right credentials of database.

finally works!